# Bash Read First Line of File with Variable Assignment

Tags: shell, variable

Unity has a variable assignment in a file called "ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt" but when I try to read it, it tries to run and throws an error.

The first line of the file is `m_EditorVersion: 2021.3.6f1`

```
% $(head -n 1 ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt)
> zsh: command not found: m_EditorVersion:
```

I am trying to come up with a one-liner that sets the value `2021.3.6f1` to a bash variable. I have tried `foo=$(head -n 1 ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt) | awk '{ print $2 }'` but run into the error (above).

Comment: Why is a question with a `zsh` error message tagges as `bash`...?

Comment: Your shell output shows the command `$(head ...`, not `foo=$(head...`

Comment: Tags have been addressed. I am running bash on Jenkins but threw an example into terminal for this post. And I didn't assign it to a var since the echo of that threw the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` you can do it on this way:

```
foo=$(awk 'NR==1{ print $2 }' ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt)
```

this take in consideration only first line (`NR==1`) and print the second element. And assign it to variable

As suggested in comment the command can be simplified:

```
foo=$(awk '{ print $2;exit }' ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.  Used sed to grab the first line, replace ": " with simple "=" and so on...

```
$ cat foo.txt
m_EditorVersion: 2013.3.6f1
xxx: aaa
yyy: bbb
$ . <(sed -n '1{s/: /=/p}' foo.txt)
$ echo $m_EditorVersion
2013.3.6f1
$
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that...?

Comment: It is always good to see different approaches but it seems overkill.  `read -r _ val < file`  might be a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

[Romeo Nimov's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/748247) is good (it's better to do this with awk alone than with head & awk), as is the variant in @Paul_Pedant's comment but it doesn't tell you what the actual problem with your command was.

You ran:

```
foo=$(head -n 1 ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt) | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

The problem here is that the pipe to `awk` is **outside** of the [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), so it was unable to modify the output of `head` - the entire unmodified first line of the file was being assigned to variable `foo`.

Meanwhile, `awk` received no input because all of the output from `head` was being assigned to $foo.  Also, any output from awk would not have been captured by the command substitution so would have just gone to stdout.

If you wanted to do it with head and awk, you'd do it like this:

```
foo=$(head -n 1 ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Note that the parentheses of the `$()` command substitution surround the entire `head | awk` pipeline, not just the `head` command.